# How do I get PayPal missing error codes in PayPal Manager?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

PayPal Guest check out denying payments but not returning error codes to PayPal Manager. How how do I get data for denied transaction attempts moving forward?  We need to track the code PayPal sends us when they reject a credit card.   We are using PayPal Adaptive Payments API on a .NET platform.

Comment: The error codes are labeled as "Response codes" within the "Custom Report" of the Manager website

Answer (score 0):

manager.paypal.com will only show codes returned by the Payflow API (payflowpro.paypal.com) and the Payflow Link web application (payflowlink.paypal.com)

Adaptive Payments uses the endpoint svcs.paypal.com , and its API responses and web declines are not reported or tracked anywhere , much less in manager.paypal.com which is a separate system

If you are indeed using Adaptive Payments, you need to log your own API call responses.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Apparently PayPal doesn't know this and the advise they sent via TT was the above and as you correctly pointed out the error codes are not supplied..